# Randomly Run Failed with simple cout project

Tags: c++, netbeans

When using this simple snippet

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "Joris" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get randomly this result:
Joris
or
RUN FAILED.

Behaviour occurs with internal terminal or standard output in project settings.
I run under openSUSE Netbeans 7.0.1 with GCC.

Comment: This snippet shouldn't compile. You don't include the `iostream` header and don't qualify `cout` with `std::`. Please post the full code.

Comment: It is a snippet not the complete code. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same result with the following?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Joris" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That with an extra namespace is the code.
Replacing the return with 1 or adding a cin does not fix the issue of randomly running the code. I also tried disabling some profile tooling etc. Nothing affects the result.

While running the code in a console always works. What makes sense because the code is perfect.

Comment: After reading a zillion pages more, it seems to be a bug in NetBeans with small codes. I'm going to vote for a bug report or report it a new one.

Comment: @Joris: Your code didn't actually include the `iostream` contents, which is a big difference.  And since even with an `include <iostream>`, there's no such thing as `cout` without `std`, yours shouldn't have even compiled in multiple ways.

Comment: I know. And that is in my code but not in this snippet. Purpose of a snippet is to leave the common stuff out of it and put the focus on the "real" core.

Anyhow, I reported it as a bug.

Comment: @Joris: I'm glad you've figured out what's happening.  In the future, if your snippets are compilable, then we don't have to guess whether something missing is causing your problem.  I recommend self-contained snippets where possible.